# Jquery cycle different delay for each images

Tags: jquery, delay, jquery-cycle

I would like to have different delay for the images of a slideshow. I'm using cycle.js but i'm open to another slideshow plugin if it is not possible with cycle.js

For example, 
fist image need to be displayed for 3 seconds
second image for 8 seconds.
2 next images for 4 second each.

Is it possible, any idea is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: use `timeoutFn` option  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html